# Get previous value after update - MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which includes id and name

```
---    -----  
id     name
---    -----
1      pete
```

My scenarios looks like this

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id=1";

previous name - ''
current name - pete
```

Now i'l update

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET name='dave' WHERE id=1";

previous name - pete
updated name - dave

$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET name='Alan' WHERE id=1";

previous name - dave
updated name - Alan
```

So after i update this table, i wanted to fetch previous record which was present in it. In my example i should get previous name as well as updated name. How to achieve this

Comment: You do this by not updating the record.  It sounds like you have a business problem -- perhaps a need for a slowly changing dimension -- and `update` is not the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using the `OLD` and `NEW` keywords on [a trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) on your table.

Although, i see that you tagged your post as php and I guess you want to get the old value in php, and to do this, you have to do a `SELECT` before the `UPDATE` to get the old name, and another `SELECT` after the `UPDATE` to get the new name.

Answer (score 7):

If you are updating *one* row and you want the previous name, you can use variables:

```
set @prevname = '';

update table_name
    set name = if(@prevname := name, 'Alan', 'Alan')
    where id = 1;

select @prevname;
```

However, I suspect that you really want a slowly changing dimension, and `update` is not the right operation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fetch the previous name unless you save it to your table as a backup.

If you want to achieve this create one more column in your table and save the current name before updating to the new one.