# On UPDATE, can SQL report which columns have changed to a new value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that represents a single record from a table in my database.  The data on the page is saved as a whole, and this data is sent to the server for processing and updating the record.

The page inputs are sent to this script

```
$values = getValidatedValues([
    'name',
    'status',
    'duration',
    'notes
]);
$sql = "UPDATE 'things' SET name=$values['name'], status=$values['status'], duration=$values['duration'], notes=$values['notes'])  WHERE id='$id'";
mysqli_query($dblink, $sql);
```

I want to know exactly what the user has changed and what they have left unchanged - despite saving the entire record in one go.

For example, in the case where a user only updates a single one of these values, like the status, what is the easiest way to discover what has actually been changed in the database?

I can always use PHP to load the original record and compare its current values with the new values - but I was hoping that there might be a way of doing this with SQL, or at least a more efficient way of finding out what has actually changed without successive calls to the database.

My question is: does SQL have any way of reporting back which columns it has actually changed to a new value?

If not, what is the single most efficient way to find out what is actually being changed in the database?

---

EDIT: [This is not a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698902/get-previous-value-after-update-mysql) - that question is concerned with what the old values were, I want to know what columns have changed (regardless of the old values).

Comment: Are you sure about that code? It's widely open to SQL injection

Comment: @Jimmery, look into triggers.

Comment: @NicoHaase it is a backend system, getValidatedValues does some protection & the code is highly simplified

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as I want to know what columns changes, not what the old values were

Comment: There is no SQL or PHP api that can give you the changed column !

Comment: Depending on your need, maybe using triggers can help you achieve what you want as in triggers you can get the field(s) that has been changed

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you unmark this - because this is not a duplicate of that question - the answers to that question will not tell me what columns have changed, only the old values (which I am not interested in)

Comment: @RahmouniRabii thank you for trying to help - I have never used triggers before, and I am looking into this - it would be great if you could add an answer suggesting how I could use these triggers, but I guess that is not possible whilst this question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate :(

Comment: @Jimmery https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKJgS_2Cevs